# Virtualenv doesn't work after cloning repository

Tags: python, git, github, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I clone my Script from Github. Then I install the requirements.txt with Gitbash.

```
1.) source ../venv/Scripts/activate
2.) pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If I try now to run the script some packages are missing everytime.
Then I need to manually install them and it is just unconvenient.

```
python script.py  # ModuleNotFoundError: No modul named 'dateutil'
```

And I really dont know what I am making wrong. My Goal is after Cloning and installing to the venv it should work but it doesnt work.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.0

$ pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from c:\users\user\desktop\dokumente\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

$ pip show --files python-dateutil
WARNING: Package(s) not found: python-dateutil

$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting aniso8601==7.0.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/a4/b4fcadbdab46c2ec2d2f6f8b4ab3f64fd0040789ac7f065eba82119cd602/aniso8601-7.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asn1crypto==0.24.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astroid==2.2.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/ad/7221a62a2dbce5c3b8c57fd18e1052c7331adc19b3f27f1561aa6e620db2/astroid-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs==19.1.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/96/d828354fa2dbdf216eaa7b7de0db692f12c234f7ef888cc14980ef40d1d2/attrs-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Automat==0.7.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/86/14c16bb98a5a3542ed8fed5d74fb064a902de3bdd98d6584b34553353c45/Automat-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\user\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b1\fe\08\84d2143069bc44c20127c38cc1bf202332319b3da7315ca766\camelcase-0.2-cp38-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi==2019.9.11
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/b0/8146a4f8dd402f60744fa380bc73ca47303cccf8b9190fd16a827281eac2/certifi-2019.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi==1.12.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/1a/ab8c62b5838722f29f3daffcc8d4bd61844aa9b5f437341cc890ceee483b/cffi-1.12.3.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\desktop\dokumente\agent_venv\venv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-onw899ll\\cffi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-onw899ll\\cffi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onw899ll\cffi\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onw899ll\cffi\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onw899ll\cffi\setup.py", line 127, in <module>
        if sys.platform == 'win32' and uses_msvc():
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onw899ll\cffi\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
        return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 225, in try_compile
        self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
        self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\user\desktop\dokumente\agent_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "c:\users\user\desktop\dokumente\agent_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1075, in __init__
        self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
      File "c:\users\user\desktop\dokumente\agent_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 547, in __init__
        vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vs_ver())
      File "c:\users\user\desktop\dokumente\agent_venv\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 561, in _find_latest_available_vs_ver
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I hope you can help me. If you need some extra information to solve the problem then please tell it to me.

Best Regards

Cren

Comment: Can you share "pip install -r requirements.txt" output ?

Comment: `which python`? `which pip`? `python --version`? `pip --version`? `pip --list | grep -F dateutil`? `pip show --files python-dateutil`?

Comment: @AliYaman I add the output

Comment: @phd I added all but by pip --list it doesnt know what command list is

Comment: Yep, sorry, it's `pip list`, my fault. `pip list | grep -F dateutil`

Comment: `cffi` is a project written in C. You need a C/C++ compiler: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Comment: Not all packages from `requirements.txt` were installed including `python-dateutil` because the installation was aborted in the middle. That's why you cannot `import dateutil`

Comment: ok but why does it work on my homepc and on my laptop not. I try to fix it tomorrow maybe creating a new virtualenv

Comment: Most probably because you have the compiler at the homepc and don't have it on the laptop.